# entropy change during irreversible heat loss

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

When a thermodynamic system gains heat if the heat gain is irreversible then there is a entropy generation along with the entropy transfer..so is there a similar entropy generation associated with irreversie heat loss too? This is the second time i am askng this question so can somebody give me a good answer..?

Comment: yeah thath question was also asked by me..I was just desperate to get some answer.So i just put it up in different way..can you answer it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just for the other system, which is gaining heat. Entropy is lowered for the system loosing heat (negative $Q$), but is increased (even more than what was lowered) for the external system gaining heat (positive $Q$).

$$\Delta S \geq \int \frac{dQ}{T}$$

Usually I have seen it denoted as

$$\Delta S = \int \frac{dQ}{T}+\sigma_{gen}$$

where the generated entropy added because of irriversibilities is added, and $\sigma_{gen}=0$ for the reversible proces.

Comment: but the heat loss is irreversible how can it be calculated by that eq..wat ia m trying to understand is does clausious inequality applies for heat irreversible loss